# How do you get vibrancy extension on VS code without admin rights?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I don't have admin rights on my computer, and want to download a extension like vibrancy on my computer. I think there is another extension like it, but I can't find it.

I tried downloading it, but you need admin rights for it.
SO What should I do?

Thank in advance.

Faizan

Comment: You mean you are not the owner of your computer? You should ask your IT department and/or colleagues in that case. Do you mean for *downloading* you need admin rights? Are you copying the download directly to your program files? Why not use VSCode's built in extension search? You should be able to find the extension there. I'm suspicious of extensions you have to manually install.

Comment: It's either the extension author(s) or your machine administrator(s) that might help you out, not anyone here.

Comment: Are you sure about that?